# Error "zsh: event not found: a[" while using grep + awk

Tags: awk, terminal, grep

I used command before and it worked fine, but now there is some error:

```
grep -oha "domain\.com/[^\"]*" "/Users/test5/folder5” -r | grep -v word1 | grep -v word2 | awk '!a[$0]++' > results
```

In the folder5 there are many files in which I need to find "domain.com" string and then filter duplicates and then write results to file.

But I have error:

```
zsh: event not found: a[
```

What is wrong with my command?

Thank you!

Comment: After the `/Users` path there is a "beautified" quote `”` - that might be the problem...

Comment: This is just right)) How it transformed to "beautified" is mistery))

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @boppy in a comment is correct:

> After the /Users path there is a "beautified" quote ” - that might be the problem...